# Reprojection issue from WGS84 to UTM32

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

In QGIS I want to transform a point shapefile from WGS84 to UTM32 (EPSG:4647). The result moves the point from somewhere in Norway to a position off the coast of Congo, Africa. Can anyone explain what's wrong?

Comment: What exactly are you doing? You have to use "save as" to transform a layer. If you simply change the system in its properties you use the same coordinate values but tell QGIS that they belong to a different system. I guess that's what's happened?

Comment: @alex that is a valid EPSG code (4647). It has axes order of easting,northing and false northing is 32500000 meters.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @bugmenot123, you have to save your layer as a new layer in order to take into account the new CRS you need. Here are the steps to follow:

- Right-click on layer name in the Layers group (see screenshot below)
- Select `UTM32` as a CRS
- Give your layer a new name > click OK
- Add the new layer in QGIS and check your points position

[image]

Comment: If you have used `Set Layer CRS`, you better switch it back **before** reprojecting with `Save As ...`. Else you will still get wrong results.